# Converting IPLimage <> texture2d in unity3d using openCVSharp

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Like the subject says. i am trying to implement openCVSharp surf in unity3d and kinda stuck in the converting part from iplimage to texture2d. Also considering that this converting proces should run at least at 25 fps. So any tips or suggestions are very helpfull!

Comment: heey, no, I dont have any code for this part. I have no idea where to start. I figured, however, it has to be done somehow without system.drawing. Because, that part is simply not available in the unity code structure. This guy has something working: http://www.ivanozanchetta.com/?p=83. I was thinking to get the pixels from texture2d and copy them to a newly iplimage, but again, no idea and google is not really helping at the moment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, I am working on the same thing now and here is my solution:

```
void IplImageToTexture2D (IplImage displayImg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float b = (float)displayImg[i, j].Val0;
            float g = (float)displayImg[i, j].Val1;
            float r = (float)displayImg[i, j].Val2;
            Color color = new Color(r / 255.0f, g / 255.0f, b / 255.0f);
            videoTexture.SetPixel(j, height - i - 1, color);
        }
    }
    videoTexture.Apply();
}
```

But it is a bit slow.
Still trying to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(640, 480);
CvMat img = new CvMat(640, 480, MatrixType.U8C3);

byte[] data = new byte[640 * 480 * 3];
Marshal.Copy(img.Data, data, 0, 640 * 480 * 3);
tex.LoadImage(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance use Unity3d's undocumented function LoadRawTextureData :

```
Texture2D IplImageToTexture2D(IplImage img)
{
    Texture2D videoTexture = new Texture2D(imWidth, imHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    byte[] data = new byte[imWidth * imHeight * 3];
    Marshal.Copy(img.ImageData, data, 0, imWidth * imHeight * 3);
    videoTexture.LoadRawTextureData(data);
    videoTexture.Apply();
    return videoTexture;
}
```